# Visual Studio type confusion

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a strange problem when I compile with Visual Studio (compiling with MSBuild seem fine).

I have a library (I will call it `A`) with a method `SetCMState()` that previously had a parameter of type `System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState`, and I changed to instead use a `Dictionary<string, object>`. So I removed the dependency for `System.Web' from this particular assembly. And everything compiles, without error.

I then use this library in a project (I will call it `B`), but when I call the above method from the library, Visual Studio refuses to compile, and cites a need to include a reference to 'System.Web'.

> CS0012 The type 'HttpSessionState' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

But I'm calling the method with the dictionary, not the `HttpSessionState`, and there are no overload, so why does Visual Studio keep trying to use the old signature instead of the new one?

Also, when I open project `B` in Visual Studio and go to the definition of the method `SetCMState` from library `A` (opening it with the tag "from metadata", since I use the assembly directly), I see *both* methods, which doesn't make any sense since both methods *never* existed at the same time (I changed the signature, I didn't create an overload).

It seems to be some bizarre caching issue, but I can't figure how it happened.
Also, the problem seems to go away (without changing any code of the project/build file) after a while, but it reappears if I change computers.

Comment: What do you mean with _since I use the assembly directly_? If you mean that you have added a reference to the assembly browsing to a particular location on your drive instead of linking it to the project included in the solution you should be absolutely sure to update the file reference to the latest built

Comment: Have you made sure, that project B uses the new version of your assembly A?

Comment: Either make sure the dll is updated, or simply put the two projects in the same solution and reference the other project instead of the dll.

Comment: Perhaps you should call the method (that uses `Dictionary`) explicitly including the namespace that you intended instead of `System.Web`. Or maybe, the issue is not that method, but somewhere else.

Comment: Is there another project you've not yet mentioned that also references A and is referenced by B that may not have had its A reference updated?

Comment: **Steve**, i have added a reference to the assembly (the .dll to be clear).  
**casiosmu**, yes, i used JustDecompile and the dll only has one metodh with a dictionary as parameter.  
**Nyerguds**, i can't reference the project directly.  
**kurakura88**, i'm not sure i follow you, i reference the metodh directly.  
**Damien_The_Unbeliever**, i checked no, also visualstudio error point directly to the row where i call the function

Answer (score 0):

The error is very concise

> CS0012 The type 'HttpSessionState' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System. Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

[The HttpSessionState Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Requires** : System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

Ergo, the *Assembly* you are calling requires `System.Web`

Either add it to your project or, remove the reference from the *Assembly* if its not needed.

**Tip** make sure you clean and rebuild just to make sure there are no [Shenanigans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenanigans) going on

However, my gut feeling is there is still a reference to it, or some other assembly does

**Update**

If you really want to know if its referenced, or something else references it. use an [Dependency Walker](https://www.google.com.au/search?ei=Dqu8WrrVIdTujwO6m6b4CQ&q=assembly%20walker%20C%23&oq=assembly%20walker%20C%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3440.4343.0.4646.3.3.0.0.0.0.271.271.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.270...0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.px4ISDirw74)

Comment: OP understands the error that is reported, he does not understand how it was caused as the conventional solution you suggest is not relevant here.

Comment: @Glubus correct on both parts, i call shenanigans though

Comment: I agree, my point is that your answer does not solve OPs problem, and - seeing as you agree with me on this - tries not to either. Maybe you should consider deleting your post and place a comment instead. (truth be told, this question is inherently akward to resolve by anyone but OP himself).

Comment: @TheGeneral i also call shenanigans, the problem is that no one reference system.web, i checked, i tried removing the assembly and re-building it, but i dosen't work, also as i said  the assembly that visualstudio "see", it's wrong (i can't find a better way to say it), i never had both a metodh with an httpstate and an overload with a dictionary, i _always_ had _only_ one of the two! Confirmed with JustDecompile